# Why can't I overload this constructor?

Tags: c++

I am coding a class to help with models.
There is a snippet of code, this one (from the .cpp file):

```
Model GameModels::getModel(std::string& gameModelName){
    return GameModelList.at(gameModelName);
}
```

Which throws this error:

> Models.h:44:9: error: ‘Models::Model
>   Models::GameModels::getModel(std::string&)’ cannot be overloaded
>   Model getModel(std::string& gameModelName);
>            ^ Models.h:40:9: error: with ‘Models::Model Models::GameModels::getModel(std::string&)’    Model
>   getModel(std::string& gameModelName);

on g++. Here is my Model definition:

```
struct Triangle{
    VertexFormat x;
    VertexFormat y;
    VertexFormat z;
};

struct Model{
    unsigned int vao;
    std::vector<unsigned int> vbos;
    std::vector<Triangle> geometry;
    std::string shaderFilepath;
    Model(){}
};
```

Comment: Where are you attempting to overload a constructor?? And where is `GameModel`, the actual class causing the problem? Please come back with your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: perhaps it would help your answer if there were some more code snippets from GameModels

Comment: Well, the first snippet is the part of models.cpp that causes the problem.

Comment: Why have you posted the definition of `Model` (which is tangential to the question) and not `GameModels` (which is right in the centre of it)?

Comment: If that snippet really is in a `.cpp` file, then please also show the lines of `Model.h` that the error message refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message (which has nothing to do with the posted code), you declare the same function twice, at lines 40 and 44 of `Model.h`.

Comment: I have an include guard, and the function is defined in main.cpp.

Comment: @user3166785: So why does the error message say `Models.h`? That rather implies that it's in a header. Please show us the code lines that the error message refers to.

Comment: Because it is overloaded in Models.h . I have on line 44 of Models.h this:   

 Model getModel(std::string& gameModelName);

which refers to the first snippet.
@MikeSeymour

Comment: @user3166785: And what does line 40 say?

Comment: Oh, so that's why :D Thanks!